# PHP SOAP Client - sending serialised .NET object

Tags: php, .net, web-services, soap

We are trying to interact with a SOAP server written in .NET. One of the parameters for one of the calls is a serialised, base64 encoded .NET object:

```
<parameter>base64Binary</parameter>
```

Although I do know the rough make up of the .NET object, I’m at a loss of how to serialise a PHP array/object appropriately for the SOAP server to handle. Obviously PHP and .NET’s serialisation methods are not the same so it’s not going to be as simple as that. The .NET object is also quite complex and is made up of a number of child objects to make things more fun. We have no control over the .NET code either.

Does anyone have any advice on how to handle such a scenario?

Comment: find a different SOAP sever, the one in question violates the core principals of SOAP.  Even if you can create said object it may be difficult to maintain in the future.  The whole idea behind soap is to allow different languages a common interface to communicate over the web.  Which becomes impossible once you start embedding a language in it.  It's badly designed and you shouldn't have to shoe horn your code to do that.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix thanks your comment confirms what I was concerned with.